# Rails NameError: uninitialized constant on initial load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nameerror

I have a weird recurring error: every time a worker is booted, it fails on the first attempt and then will work from there on. Each time I get the same error.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Models::ScorecardVirtualAttributes::LevelCalculator
```

So I ran through the usual checks: first I checked to see if it was spelt right. Then I checked to see if it was dependent on a gem that was not included somehow, which it is not.

I think I have replicated the failure in the console. On the initial boot up of the console I run this:

```
[1] toolkit »  defined? Models::ScorecardVirtualAttributes::LevelCalculator
  => nil
[2] toolkit »  defined? ::Models::ScorecardVirtualAttributes::LevelCalculator
  => nil
[3] toolkit »  Models::ScorecardVirtualAttributes::LevelCalculator
  => Models::ScorecardVirtualAttributes::LevelCalculator < Object
[4] toolkit »  defined? ::Models::ScorecardVirtualAttributes::LevelCalculator
  => "constant"
```

As you can see, when I check to see if it is defined it fails initially. But then after calling it directly it returns the expected "constant" when I check to see if it is defined.

I then thought that perhaps it's not being loaded correctly. Here's what I have in my `config/application.rb`:

```
# Within config/application.rb
...
config.autoload_paths += %W( #{Rails.root}/lib) #/models
```

I have the `lib/models` directory added to the `autoload_paths`, and the model that doesn't seem to be loading initially is in `lib/models/scorecards_virtual_attributes/level_calculator.rb`.

Is there perhaps something else that could cause this? Or is there something wrong with what I am doing?

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3 doesn’t autoload files under the lib directory itself. If you are using Rails 3 or above, you will have to load it in config/application.rb.